# Set theory combinatronics, number of walk function

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

I am taking a coursera course on discrete math and I have this question that I have hard time figuring out, on how to proceed, any explanation to solution would be highly appreciated.

$$\textrm{A function} \quad \{0,\dots,n\} \rightarrow {Z} \quad \textrm{is a walk function if consecutive values differ by exactly 1, i.e.,} \left |f(i)=(i-1) \right |=1 \quad \textrm{for all} \quad 1=1\dots, n \quad \textrm{ How many walk functions are there from } \{0,\dots,6\} \quad \textrm {to} \quad \mathbb{Z} \quad \textrm{with} \quad f(0)=f(6)=0?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Surely you mean $|f(i)-f(i-1)|=1$.  As for a hint on how to proceed, there will be some times where you "walk forward" and other times where you "walk back."  Figure out *how many* times you must walk forward and how many times you must walk back.  Now... how many steps did you take overall?  Finally, in how many ways can we choose which of the steps we take are the forward steps (*letting the rest be the backwards steps*).

Comment: Additional hint: An example of a walk function from $\{0,1,\dots,6\}\to\Bbb Z$ satisfying $f(0)=f(6)=0$ might be $0,1,2,3,2,1,0$

Comment: if I got you correctly then 0,1,2,3,2,1,0,  or 0,1,0, or 0,2,3,4,3,2,1,0 are as well

Comment: 0,2,3,4,3,2,1,0 is not a walk function because the first step was too large.  Further, neither 0,1,0 nor 0,2,3,4,3,2,1,0 are functions from $\{0,1,\dots,6\}$.  0,1,0 is too short and 0,2,3,4,3,2,1,0 is too long.  Another example of a walk function from $\{0,1,\dots,6\}$ to $\Bbb Z$ might be $0,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0$

Comment: To emphasize the point... and to hopefully clear up whatever confusion, the notation I use above is that of a sequence (*which these are examples of*).  If you insist on writing it this way, you could write my second example instead as $\begin{cases}f(0)=0\\f(1)=1\\f(2)=0\\f(3)=-1\\f(4)=-2\\f(5)=-1\\f(6)=0\end{cases}$

Comment: now it getting cleaner so the number of functions has to be 7 with 0 and it difference has to be 1 but what my confusion is are  the natural numbers and are they always have to start and end with a 0

Comment: Intuitively, a walk function represents your position as a function of time if at every time step you either go right or left one unit.  The question is asking how many ways you can take six steps and return to where you start.  If it asked for two steps there would be two, you could go right-left or left-right and the functions would be $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,-1,0)$

Comment: "*Do they always have to start and end with $0$?*"  Not unless if the problem specifies that they do.  Your problem does specify that with the line "*...with $f(0)=f(6)=0$*"  As for your first part of the question... "*my confusion is are the natural numbers...*" I'm not quite able to figure out what you mean by this.  In the given example, your function must have domain $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  The codomain is the set of *integers*.  There are some similar questions where we insist that the codomain must be the natural numbers instead, but that is a bit harder.  (*See catalan numbers on wiki*)

Comment: so based on what I am getting then the 0,1,0,1,0,1,0 is also a walk function so is 0,1,2,1,2,1,0

Comment: @RossMillikan so for the 4 steps it would be $$\textrm{A function} \quad \{0,1,2,1,0\},\{0,-1,-2,-1,0\},\{0,-1,0,-1,0\},\{0,1,0,1,0\}
 $$

Comment: You missed two.  How about $(0,1,0,-1,0)$ and the reverse?

Comment: You seem to now have a rather firm understanding of *what* a walk function is and what a few examples the specific walk functions you are asked to count in the problem.  Now, all that remains is to count them... but as always in a course in introductory combinatorics, you should never put yourself in a position where you try to count them by hand.  You should be able to generalize this to larger problems (*what if it was 1000 steps being taken instead of only 6*).  Use your counting techniques you have already learned and try to relate this problem to one you already know how to solve.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think the idea of this function is that coming up wit formula, like if it was 5 it would be 0 functions, while if it 4 it 6, so it hard to just relay on known combination formulas.

Comment: And again, I encourage you to go back to my very first comment and to look at the answer below by Sebastian.  You should know how to count how many binary strings of length six there are which have exactly three ones and three zeroes.  You should also be able to see why the question of counting binary strings with exactly three ones and three zeroes has exactly the same answer as the original question you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate what has been said in the comments above, a function $f$ from $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}\to\Bbb Z$ is called a "walk function" (*or equivalently a walk sequence*) iff $|f(i)-f(i-1)|=1$ for all $i\in\{1,2,3\dots,n\}$.  The intuitive interpretation is that you have a person who every second moves exactly one unit away from where he just was in any direction possible.  In our case here, we are working in the one-dimensional case (*only forwards or backwards*) but as problems become more complicated we may open ourselves up to more possible directions of movement.

You will eventually revisit these types of functions when you study [random walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk).

For now, as per the instructions of the problem we limit our focus specifically to those walk functions from $\{0,1,2,\dots,6\}\to\Bbb Z$ satisfying $f(0)=f(6)=0$, that is to say, those walks where our person takes a total of six steps and ends where he began.

An example of a walk sequence satisfying those conditions might be: $$\begin{cases}f(0)=0\\f(1)=-1\\f(2)=0\\f(3)=1\\f(4)=2\\f(5)=1\\f(6)=0\end{cases}$$

Notice that the above example could have been described a different way... instead of describing it in terms of the position of our person at each time, we could have described it as the direction that our person walked each time he took a step.  Using $+$ to denote forward movement and $-$ to denote backward movement, the above example could have instead been notated as:

$$-+++--$$

Notice, that every walk function from $\{0,1,2,\dots,6\}\to\Bbb Z$ satisfying $f(0)=f(6)=0$ could be described uniquely instead as a length $6$ sequence of exactly three $+$'s and three $-$'s and vice versa.  That is to say, there exists a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between the sets of objects described by the two problems.

We ought to be more rigorous in proving that there is indeed a bijection between the two sets, but if it is obvious or a well known example then it is common to skip this step, only providing clarification upon request.

> Explicitly, going from a walk function to a sequence of $+$'s and $-$'s, set the $k$'th entry in the sequence as a $+$ if $f(k)-f(k-1)=1$ and set the $k$'th entry in the sequence as a $-$ if $f(k)-f(k-1)=-1$.  We should then take the time to show that this process will never have two different walk functions mapping to the same sequence, and further every sequence is mapped to by some walk function.  It is worth taking the time to work through such a proof at least a few times.

One of the most important counting principles you will ever learn is that if there is a bijection between two sets, then they must be of the same size.  That is to say, if we have our first problem and it sounds strange or difficult to approach, but we can in a convenient way explain exactly why there are the same number of solutions to the first problem as there are for a second related problem, then we may simply solve the second problem and know that the answer to the first problem will be the same.

Here, we were able to spot the convenient bijection between our original problem of counting how many walk functions there are with those limitations, to the problem of counting how many sequences of $+$'s and $-$'s there are, so we instead solve that.

---

So, the question becomes "How many length 6 sequences of $+$'s and $-$'s exist with exactly three $+$'s and exactly three $-$'s?"

This is going to be a direct application of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

---

As you go on to try to generalize the formula you found to other or larger numbers, you should notice that there are no walk functions from $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}\to\Bbb Z$ where $f(0)=f(n)=0$ in the case that $n$ is odd.  That is perfectly fine, and you can include that in your final formula by using piece-wise defined function notation.  Letting $F(n)$ denote the number of walk functions from $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}\to\Bbb Z$ where $f(0)=f(n)=0$, you will have

$$F(n)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\\&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\end{cases}$$

where I intentionally left the expression for when $n$ is even blank for you to fill in yourself.

Comment: tanks for helping me, but my question now is what if instead of exactly it at most 1

Comment: Relate those functions to sequences using `+`'s, `-`'s and now also `o`'s.  For example the sequence `+o--+o` would correspond to the walk $0,1,1,0,-1,0,0$ while the sequence `++oo--` would correspond to the walk $0,1,2,2,2,1,0$, etc...  Now... break into cases based on how many `+`'s were used.  If you want the walk to start and end in the same place, there must be the same number of `-`'s.  Knowing the length of the walk and knowing the number of `+`'s, this will tell you how many `-`'s and how many `o`'s there are.  Count how many sequences of `+,-,o` exist of that length with those amounts

Comment: To answer this, it is just repeated application of binomial coefficients.  Alternatively, you could instead use multinomial coefficients.

Comment: but what if it an odd number like 7 I thought I could just do c(7 3)+c(7 2)+c(7 7)

Comment: The approach is identical regardless of the parity of $n$ for the modified problem.  Your attempt is way off.  Reread my earlier explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is useful to have in mind an equivalent problem. In this case, let's suppose you're standing on a step of some long stairs and you ask yourself: *In how many ways can I go up and down the stairs taking only one step at a time so that after six movements I end up exactly where I am now?* Then you realize that for every step you take upwards you have to take another downwards and hence there are in total three of each. Now suppose $1$ means take a step upward, while $0$ means go down one step, then solving your problem ammounts to finding the number of binary chains of the type $101100$, $001101$, etc.